# How do I insert multiple rows in POST body? Google Fusion Tables API V1.0

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I could insert rows by QueryString sql parameter. https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/query/sql?hl=ja

But the reference document describes that you can use sql parameter as body of POST for inserting rows. I can't. How do I do? https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using?hl=ja#insertRow

First reference describes that QueryString sql parameter required. I got error 400 by omitting sql in QueryString. Using QueryString has limitation(URL length). I want to insert many rows in body of POST.

request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?access_token={my access token} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
sql=INSERT INTO 1JOgUG5QWE5hybrDAd2GX3yfjVCGoM6u7WkSVDok ('_id', '_count', 'start_time', 'end_time',  'counts', 'start_plaece', 'end_place', 'distance',  'average_speed', 'send_flag', 'time_span', 'train_type',  'calories', 'weight', 'status', 'map_url', 'rally_id' ) VALUES ('-1', '0', '2013/01/19 09:00:00.000', '2013/01/19 12:34:56.000', '9876', 'Tokorozawa3', 'iidabashi2', '45678',  '67', '0', '986532', '1', '389', '77.70', '0', 'http://www.google.com/',  '3');
```

response:

```
body {
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "required",
     "message": "Required parameter: sql",
     "locationType": "parameter",
     "location": "sql"
    }
   ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Required parameter: sql"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sanya helped me with a similar problem today ([see thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698341/oauth-oauthconfig-google-apps-script-fusion-table-api-sql-insert-problems/15704086)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is faulty and there are some deatils missing.

You can use the sql=... **parameter in the request url**. The ContentType header usually is application/json but the API probably accepts other too. In this case you're limited in 2048 characters URL length.

You van also use sql=... **in the POST body**. In this case you have to set the **ContentType must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. You are limited to 500 INSERT statements in 1 request.

Another option is to use the importRows method. Here you will use a **CSV as the POST body**. In this method you're limited by 100MB uploaded data. **The ContentType must be "application/octet-stream"**. 
More details here: [importRows reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows)

Comment: It worked. the ContentType you mentioned is correct. Thank you!